# Download PDF into Webapplication(.Net) from SSRS URL access method

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am trying to download a pdf file from SSRS server to my .net application. I am using URL access method to get byte data from the SSRS-URL (http://SsrsDevServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMainFolder%2fReports%2fInvoice&rs:Command=Render&). My .net application code is shown below.

Note : by making Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true; and without credentials part, it works as expected only in my local machine, but failing when I published it to DEV server.

```
        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
       // Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        string strReportUser = "USERNAME";
        string strReportUserPW = "PAssword";
        string strReportUserDomain = "Domain";


        Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
                    strReportUser,
                    strReportUserPW,
                    strReportUserDomain);

        byte[] myDataBuffer = Client.DownloadData(theURL);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        Response.BinaryWrite(myDataBuffer);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Appreciate any help. 
Thanks!

Comment: quick question, logging with given credentials on browser (reporting website) and then in new tab (same browser window) firing same url does it download report for you?

Comment: @AnkUser, Yes the URL(reporting website) works fine itself with given credentials in different tab in any server. URL with given credentials (through .net app) also works in localhost(but not in DEV server) with by making Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true and by commenting out credentials code;

Comment: Resolved the issue by replacing the above code with code shown below:

Comment: string FileExtension = ".pdf"; 
if (RB_Excel.Checked)
    FileExtension = ".xls"; 
var location = TB_Dropfolder.Text + "SSRSAutomationTestReport - Customer " + TB_CustomerID.Text + FileExtension;

Comment: / When calling for the url a NTLM challenge takes place
// Once this challenge takes place the GetCredentials will automagically be called via de CredentialCache
// This will resolve the 2 step authentication
// Requirement: the uri for the cache must be the Scheme + Host of the domain

Comment: var cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(new Uri(string.Format("{0}://{1}", url.Scheme, url.Host)), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, Domain)); 
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = cc;
    client.DownloadFile(url, location);
 
    MessageBox.Show("Report is exported");
}